# How can I update the data that received from firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-android

My function that receives data =>

```
 Future<Object?> GetTotal() async {
      FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
    
      DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Total");
    
      DatabaseEvent event = await ref.once();
    
      return event.snapshot.value;
    }
```

And it's where I use it =>

```
FutureBuilder(
                      future: GetTotal(),
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          print(snapshot.error);
                        }
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          var data1 = snapshot.data!.toString();
                          var data2 = double.parse(data1);
                          String data3 = data2.toStringAsFixed(2);
                          return Text(
                            "Total Amount \n\n\n" + "${data3} TL",
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                          );
                        } else {
                          return CircularProgressIndicator();
                        }
                      }),
```

It only fetches the data when the app is opened. But I want it to fetch the data every minute or every 10 minute how can I make it?

I think the problem is in GetTotal() function `ref.once()` but what can I use instead of `ref.once()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here is to use a StreamBuilder. Every change in your "Total" node, will fire a new event, this will update the data that is shown by the StreamBuilder.

```
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("Totals");

StreamBuilder(
        stream: ref.onValue
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (chatSnapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          // do something with the snapshot
          print(snapshot.snapshot.value); // this will show what is in the data you got
          return Container(child: Text("your data"));
        });
```

Comment: How can I return "Total" nodes value?

Comment: Check out https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/database/usage/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67367446/how-to-display-data-in-listview-using-streambuilder-from-realtime-db-in-flutter I have also updated the answer to help you a bit